# Link extraction error

Tags: python, scrapy

My goal is extracting a special data within different links.For example for target links main page is http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik-daire  and i want to gathering price value from

http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/konut-satilik/istanbul-bahcelievler-bahcelievler-emlakcidan-apartman-dairesi/detay?sParam=T0CxxQ7yvMbCCAkDN0Behw==&new=1

or from another link  http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/konut-satilik/ankara-cankaya-yasamkent-emlakcidan-apartman-dairesi/detay?sParam=iM12IpDxQ9JOLFTGIwQMKg==&new=1

```
My code is like that :

import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class deneme01(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hurriyetemlak'
    allowed_domains = ['hurriyetemlak.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik-daire']
    Rule = (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]//li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),callback='parse_item')


    def parse_item(self,response):
                            item = scrapy.Item()
                            item['price']=response.selector.xpath('//li[@class="price-lineclearfix"]/text()').extract()
                            yield item
```

But i take a syntax error.I cannot figure out why it is happening.I just apply the Rule 's function .

Comment: did you use the scrapy console to test the script line?

Comment: yes i take same error >> Rule = (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]//li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),callback='parse_item')

Comment: I think your xpath is wrong. Try this: `Rule = (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]/li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),callback='parse_item')`

Answer (score 0):

Please post tracebacks when you get syntax errors.

To help other readers if they have a similar issue, I'm pasting what your spider gives me from `scrapy runspider` (I omitted the callback):

```
$ cat test001.py 
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class deneme01(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hurriyetemlak'
    allowed_domains = ['hurriyetemlak.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik-daire']
    Rule = (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]//li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),callback='parse_item')

$ scrapy runspider test001.py 
2016-03-15 11:24:25 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-03-15 11:24:25 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-03-15 11:24:25 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 143, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 89, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 150, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 80, in run
    module = _import_file(filename)
  File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/scrapy10/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/commands/runspider.py", line 20, in _import_file
    module = import_module(fname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/paul/scrapinghub/scrapy/stackoverflow/35995711/test001.py", line 11
    Rule = (LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]//li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),callback='parse_item')
                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can use scrapy docs as example of correct syntax.

`CrawlSpider` page has [this example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
        # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('category\.php', ), deny=('subsection\.php', ))),

        # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item\.php', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
        item = scrapy.Item()
        item['id'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_id"]/text()').re(r'ID: (\d+)')
        item['name'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_name"]/text()').extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath('//td[@id="item_description"]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

So you should:

- have a `rules` attribute,
- `rules` being a list or tuple of `Rule` instances

Your spider with corrected syntax (I have not tested behavior when run)

```
$ cat test002.py 
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class deneme01(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hurriyetemlak'
    allowed_domains = ['hurriyetemlak.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hurriyetemlak.com/satilik-daire']
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//ul[@id="reality-list"]//li[@onmouseover="show(this);"]')),
             callback='parse_item'),
    )
```